# How would one handle a PC vs clone fight?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer

I'm currently making a Homebrew campiagn. Near the end, I am having the PCs go through a test of skill. I can't think of much to test a sorcerer, so I was going to go with the PC fighting a phantom of themself. How would I do this without making the phantom OP or having them kill each other almost the same time? My friend also gave me the suggestion of making it a survival type test and have it so when the clone dies it spawns two clones that do the same thing. With that they would have to last a certain amount of time, but I'm still stuck with the clones possibly being to OP

Comment: I have an answer ready if you can narrow down the question. "How to balance an encounter with clones/copies of player characters" seems to be the core of your query, and what I aimed to answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Make the clone a simulacrum**

The simulacrum spell states:

> ...
>
> It appears to be the same as the original, but it has half the creature's hit point maximum and is formed without any equipment. Otherwise, the illusion uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates.
>
> ...
>
> The simulacrum is friendly to you and creatures you designate. It obeys your spoken commands, moving and acting in accordance with your wishes and acting on your turn in combat. The simulacrum lacks the ability to learn or become more powerful, so it never increases its level or other abilities, nor can it regain expended spell slots.

This gives you the flexibility to choose when the simulacrum was created (ie was it after a time when the sorcerer had used some of its spell slots, sorcery points or other abilities?).

It also means you can give it less powerful equipment than your “prime” sorcerer.

Importantly it can act on its own and the creator of the simulacrum does not necessarily have to have designated the “prime” sorcerer as a friendly creature.

To get around the long casting time have the creature that created the simulacrum use their wish spell to duplicate the effects of the simulacrum spell.

If the sorcerer has wish, it’s simulacrum can be instructed to cast wish to create copies of “prime” when they are close to being defeated.

This will necessarily limit the resources the new simulacrums have access to as the fight progresses. It will also mean that the new simulacra will have progressively lower HP as the fight goes on, reducing their challenge to the PC.

The only restriction you would need to put on the “prime” is that they need to retain their 9th level slot throughout the flight (maybe because it is required for some post-fight ritual). This is so the later simulacrum have access to the wish spell as necessary.